# Can I list my experience as independent researcher to my resume or CV?

Tags: independent-researcher

I have graduated from my master's last year. I am very much interested in doing an additional technical master's program and/or a Ph.D. in my field. So, I started applying for both the technical master's program and for the PhD program. In the meantime, I thought of not letting my research interest decay, I started working as an independent researcher. And luckily I got a collaboration offer from a foreign university professor who was a great scholar in my field of study. I collaborated with him from my home and did nearly 8 research articles within a period of 11 months. But at the same time, I was rejected by all the M.sc. and Ph.D. programs I applied. However, my independent research works were accepted and published in reputed IF international journals. Now, I am applying for the winter semester programs, in that case, can I please know whether I can add my experience as an independent researcher to my resume or Cv which I submit to the educational institutions? Please kindly help me in this regard. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Unfortunately, "independent researcher" can mean a wide spectrum of things, anything from doing serious research published in good journals (as you've done) to sitting around thinking "deep" thoughts that never lead anywhere (and might not even make sense). The important thing for your CV is to emphasize the publications that show you're at the serious end of the spectrum. The phrase "independent researcher" can fill what would otherwise look like a gap in your history, but the publications (and, as Buffy pointed out, letters of recommendation) are the real information.

Comment: Thank you very much for your comments, sir, Buffy, and Blass, I will add it in my CV, I already have a recommendation letter from the professor and since my articles are accepted to Elsevier publication above a IF of 4, I think as per your suggestions, I will add it. Once again thanks for your comment.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, absolutely add it, along with the publications that resulted. And, you should consider getting a letter of recommendation from the professor. Your lack of formal affiliation is of no consequence. It is the work that matters.

Don't hesitate here.